# running netcat inside docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have created docker images using the below Dockerfile.

```
 FROM ubuntu
 RUN apt-get update \
  && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    net-tools \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update \
  && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    netcat \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
EXPOSE 1234
ENTRYPOINT bin/bash
CMD ["nc", "-l", "1234"]
```

I created image from the above docker file and run the docker container using the image by running below command.

```
docker run -d  -i -p 1234:1234 --name daemon  nc-ubuntu nc -l 1234
```

In another terminal, I run the below command.

```
telnet localhost 1234
```

I got the below output.

```
$ telnet localhost 1234
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I am trying this as this is sample from book docker in practice in chapter 2 by manning for running docker as daemon process.

As per author I should get below result.

```
$ telnet localhost 1234
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
hello daemon
```

Any idea why I'm not getting expected output.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's never going to work.  There are several problems with your Dockerfile.

### 1

Setting `ENTRYPOINT` to `/bin/bash` means that `docker run ...` is simply going to start `bash`. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile) about `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD`.

### 2

Since you're in non-interactive mode, `bash` is going to exit immediately.  Consider:

```
host$ docker run nc-ubuntu
host$
```

Vs:

```
host$ docker run -it nc-ubuntu
root@e3e1a1f4e453:/#
```

The latter, because of the `-it` (which allocates a tty device, which bash requires in interactive mode), gets a `bash` prompt.

### 3

Neither invocation will cause the container to run `netcat`...and even if it did, nothing in your Dockerfile would generate the `hello daemon` response you're expecting.

## 4

The `nc` command line is incorrect.  The syntax is:

```
nc -l -p <port>
```

So you would need:

```
CMD ["nc", "-l", "-p", "1234"]
```

## 5

If you actually want `nc` to provide you with the `hello daemon` response, you would need to add an appropriate `-c` command to your `nc` command line, as in:

```
CMD ["nc", "-l", "-p", "1234", "-c", "echo hello daemon"]
```

This makes the final Dockerfile look like:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update \
  && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    net-tools \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get update \
  && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
    netcat \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
EXPOSE 1234
CMD ["nc", "-l", "-p", "1234", "-c", "echo hello daemon"]
```

And if I build that:

```
docker build -t nc-ubuntu .
```

And run that:

```
docker run -d  -i -p 1234:1234 --name daemon  nc-ubuntu
```

I can then telnet to port `1234` on my host and see the expected response:

```
host$ telnet localhost 1234
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
hello daemon
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

At this point, the container will have exited because `nc` exits after accepting a single connection (without additional parameters), and a Docker contain exits when the foreground process exits.

---

I don't have access to the book so I can't tell if this is do to a problem with the book or if you have made a mistake in  your implementation, but I would suggest that there are a number of online Docker tutorials that are probably at least as good.

Answer (score 6):

A simple solution that works for me -
`docker run -p 1234:1234 -it --rm alpine /bin/sh -c "nc -l -p 1234"`

From another terminal run `nc localhost 1234`